# Can't import a js on to another js uing wix and velo

Tags: javascript, velo

I have been trying to import some global variables from a mainScript to a script dedicated to a page. I have been trying to import it and it detects it but it says that the variables I'm trying to use don't exist in that script

I have two scripts

mainPage.js:

```
export var preguntas = ["pregunta 1", "pregunta 2", "pregunta 3"];
export var randomNumber = 0;
export var respuestas = [];
```

the scripts of the page I'm working on

```
import * as masterScript from "file:///public/masterPage.js";

$w.onReady(function () {
    $w("#Section1ListItem1Title1").text = masterScript.respuestas[0];
});
```

The error says:

> Property 'respuestas' does not exist on type 'typeof import("file:///public/masterPage")'.

Comment: You say the file is called `mainPage.js`, yet you're trying to import `masterPage.js`?